# Android specific imageview with button xml

Tags: android, xml

Android specific imageview with button xml

I want my imageview to be center top and below it equal size buttons ..

I tried but it never worked, the buttons never stops flowing

what I tried is the image in a relative layout then the buttons in a relative layout also but alone ..

[image]

this how I want it to be

Comment: give android:layout_width and android:layout_height equal

Comment: "buttons never stops flowing" is the most pivotal part of the post, but the most unclear. what do you mean by that. Also, please post the code/xml that you've attempted with so far.

Comment: can you post your code over here ?

Answer (score 0):

You should had used `LinearLayout` for both the ImageView and the button, and setting them to be `Center_horizontal`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```